# what is the meaning of this Linux command?

Tags: bash

I'm little bit new in sql command so please help me to clear this doubt

```
ps -ef|grep tomcat
```

Comment: That's not SQL.

Comment: This is not a sql command, this is a unix/linux command, that checks the process list for a process named `'tomcat'`.

Comment: Or `pgrep -l tomcat`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a SQL command,it's an unix/linux command check out forum answer below can clear your doubts.
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/852206/what-does-ps-efgrep-processname-mean

In short : 
look for lines containing processname in a detailed overview/snapshot of all current processes, and display those lines in **linux command prompt environment**

Answer (score 0):

`ps -ef` says list all of the processes.  (The `-e` option means every process, and the `-f` means use the "full" format in the listing.)

`|` says pipe the output of the previous command to the next command

`grep tomcat` say show (i.e. write to output) only those lines in the command's input that contain the string `tomcat`.

Combined, it means "show me the tomcat processes".

---

The "secret" to understanding a complicated Linux command is:

1. Understand the shell syntax; i.e. how `|`, `<`, `>`, `$` and so on work.
2. Break the command line into its commands
3. Look up and read the manual entry for each command.